# Apache Solr: the result is different based on order of AND

Tags: solr

I have trouble with Apache Solr now.
I wonder if there is any difference with 2 query:

```
status:1  AND province:D500  AND district:014 AND precinct:008 AND name:*THÔN 22*
```

I have `parsedquery_toString": "+status:1 +province:D500 +district:014 +precinct:008 +name:*thôn _text:22*"`

and with the second one:

```
status:1 AND name:*THÔN 22* AND province:D500  AND district:014 AND precinct:008
```

I have

```
 "parsedquery_toString": "+status:1 +name:*thôn +_text:22* +province:D500 +district:014 +precinct:008",
```

What makes the parsequery_toString to be so different with just the changes of orders of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the result of the space in `*THÔN 22*`, and how it changes the query. If it's a single search term instead of two, try quoting it and see if you get the same results then.